# How to exclude a certain key of an object when mapping it?

Tags: javascript

If I have an object, such as,

```
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}
```

I can map the keys and values as,

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`))
```

Is it possible in Javascript to omit a property, when mapping it?

Something like,

```
Object.entries({a: obj.a, ...obj}).map(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`))
```

I can do the following:

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => key !== 'a' && console.log(`${key}: ${value}`))
```

But I feel like there can be a cleaner way to do this, and also this wouldn't work, because that mapped index will contain `undefined`. Just looking to clarify this.

Comment: Why are you using `.map()` here in the first place? You're not returning anything. Seems like you are using it as a `.forEach()`.

Comment: If you want to skip properties I'd just chain a `.filter()` and then a `.map()`

Comment: I'm mapping an object to JSX elements, and I need to exclude a specific key from a form data object.

Comment: You can't achieve that by using `.map()` alone if you're using the return value. `.map()` iterates over every element and maps it to a new value. The array that is returned will always be the same length as the source array.

Comment: @MikeK If you're mapping to jsx elements, then please show us the actual code that does that.

Comment: If you wrap your method into a function you could destructure your input object to remove the `a` property and obtain the remaining properties like so: 
`const mapObj = ({a, ...obj}) =>
      Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) =>\`${key}: ${value}\`)`

Comment: Perhaps useful is `const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) => xs .flatMap ((x) => f (x) ? [m (x)] : [])`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `filter`

```
Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, _]) => key !== "a").map();
```

Comment: You can use reduce after the filter to get an object back from the entries array.

`Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, _]) => key !== "a").reduce((res, [key, value]) => ({ ...res, [key]: value}), {});`

Comment: @FilipePinheiro OP doesn't want that? And no, you shouldn't use `reduce` for that, just call `Object.fromEntries` :-)

Comment: TIL `fromEntries`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want:

```js
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
}


const res = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'a');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **hide/exclude a key when using a map** you can set its enumerable property to false, using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}

// this will hide key 'b' from obj
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', {
  enumerable: false,  
});

Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key}: ${value}`))
```